# Overlay three curves in the same y axis

Tags: r, curve, normal-distribution

I want to overlay three curves of the normal distribution with three different sigma values. I have done this:

```
curve(dnorm(x, mean(x), sd(x)), col = 2, lwd = 2)
par(new = TRUE)
curve(dnorm(x, mean(x), sd(x)/2), col = 3, lwd = 2)
par(new = TRUE)
curve(dnorm(x, mean(x), sd(x)*2), col = 4, lwd = 2)
```

And the result is[image]
But I want to use only one y axis scale, so the three plots are one under the other and not on the same y scale. Also I want to expand the range of the x axis, to be from -3 to 3 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a blank graphics device first by setting `plot` parameter `type = "n"`. Then `add = TRUE` the 3 curves.

```
plot(c(0, 1), c(0, 3), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
curve(dnorm(x, mean(x), sd(x)), col = 2, lwd = 2, add = TRUE)
curve(dnorm(x, mean(x), sd(x)/2), col = 3, lwd = 2, add = TRUE)
curve(dnorm(x, mean(x), sd(x)*2), col = 4, lwd = 2, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yaxt` and `xaxt` to remove the y axis from the graph.

```
curve(dnorm(x, mean(x), sd(x)), col = 2, lwd = 2,ylab="My y axis name")
par(new = TRUE)
curve(dnorm(x, mean(x), sd(x)/2), col = 3, lwd = 2,yaxt='n',xaxt='n',ylab="")
par(new = TRUE)
curve(dnorm(x, mean(x), sd(x)*2), col = 4, lwd = 2,yaxt='n',xaxt='n',ylab="")
```

gives,

[image]